# Calling an async function inside a button EventListener of a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to call an async parameter inside an event listener.
the first console log does show up without a problem, but the second does not.

The code:

```
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('Clicked on 2 btn update prices ');
    (async () => {
        console.log('Clicked on 2 btn update prices crossed ');
        let productslist = await enumStorage();
        const Email = await chrome.storage.local.get(['Email']);
        console.log(await enumStorageAll());
        
        //console.log(values.Link.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < productslist.length; i++) {
            //console.log(values.Link.length);
            let values = productslist[i];
            var url = 

            console.log(url);

            
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => {
                    result = response;
                    if ("Image" in result) {
                        UpdateRows(values, pricewithlink, shops, i)
                        
                    }
                    // handle the response
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    // handle the error
                });

        }

    })

});
```

Comment: You're never calling the IIFE. But there's no need for the IIFE, you can just make the event listener function async: `async event => ...`

Answer (score 3):

Since your function is anonymous (unnamed), you need to invoke it right after declaration.

```
(async () => {
    ... 
})();
```

This is the correct way of invoking such functions.

Comment: That is what was missing! Thank you

Comment: Please help OP in a comment and mark as typo instead